# Simulate a particular view among many views?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

In my project I have around 20 views . Is there any possible way in xcode to simulate a particular view ?

For example:

The flow of the views is like this:

View A-----> View B------>View C----->View D

IF I want to go to view D, I need to go through A,B,C. Is there anyway to skip this flow and simulate the View D directly?

**Note:** Kindly suggest me if there is another way than making the 'View D' as Initial view controller.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can programmatically segue to any view

go to the viewDidLoad function in your initial view controller and insert either of the following lines

```
presentViewController(viewD, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

or

```
performSegueWithIdentifier("nameOfSegueToD", sender: nil)
```

you can change the name of the segue in the attributes inspector on the right side of xCode window.

Answer (score 0):

After some research , I found there is now way to launch the particular view controller from storyboard without making it as initial view controller in the Xcode. I can still do it programmatically, but it is not possible in Xcode IB.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (id)instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier
```

Apple docs:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStoryboard_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIStoryboard/instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: